# arrange file line into tabular form

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line

This is a sample line from my file:

```
42001232  2011-07-01  51  100001  0  100002  0  2011-07-02  51  100003  0  100004  0
```

How do I arrange it to look like this

```
42001232  2011-07-01  51  100001  0
42001232  2011-07-01  51  100002  0
42001232  2011-07-02  51  100003  0
42001232  2011-07-02  51  100004  0
```

Apart from the first column, all the columns are repeating starting with a date.
I need to organize it in a tabular form. Also, the delimiter here is TAB.

Comment: sorry, I updated the question. I gave incorrect information at first. So far, what i've tried is this: 
sed "s:\t\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\):\n\1:g. And each line looked like this: 2011-07-01 51 100001 0 100002 0

Comment: What does `51` mean? would different values instead of `51` be possible in it's place of is is locked at `51`?

Comment: @Faiz `51` is just another id (integer). It could be any other value.

Comment: Are there a fixed number of pairs following "date, id"? Or will it vary?

Comment: That's a brutal format to have to process!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
}
{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i ~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/) {
            for (j=i+2;j<=NF;j+=2) {
                if ($j ~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/) {
                    break
                }
                else {
                    print $1, $i, $(i+1), $j, $(j+1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
42001232    2011-07-01  51  100001  0
42001232    2011-07-01  51  100002  0
42001232    2011-07-02  51  100003  0
42001232    2011-07-02  51  100004  0
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } { for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/) for (j=i+2;j<=NF;j+=2) if ($j ~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/) break; else print $1, $i, $(i+1), $j, $(j+1) }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on the given data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw( -no_match_vars );

$OFS = qq"\t";

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    my(@fields) = split /\s+/, $_;
    my $col1 = shift @fields;
    my $date = shift @fields;
    my $col3 = shift @fields;
    while (scalar(@fields) > 1)
    {
        if ($fields[0] =~ /^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d$/)
        {
            $date = shift @fields;
            $col3 = shift @fields;
            next;
        }
        else
        {
            my $col4 = shift @fields;
            my $col5 = shift @fields;
            print $col1, $date, $col3, $col4, "$col5\n";
        }
    }
    print STDERR "oops - debris $fields[0] left over\n" if (scalar(@fields) != 0);
}
```

The output I got is:

```
42001232        2011-07-01      51      100001  0
42001232        2011-07-01      51      100002  0
42001232        2011-07-02      51      100003  0
42001232        2011-07-02      51      100004  0
```

That's a perfectly horrid format to have to parse.  I've had to make some assumptions about the way the repetitions are handled, so that the column after a date is fixed until the next date, for example.